# CiviEvent: Participating Status not updating

Tags: civievent

CiviCRM 5.13.5, Drupal 7.67

I'm trying to update the participant status of an event through CiviEvent, to change certain participants from "Registered" to "Attended" for an event. However the changed statuses are not saving, and I can't find anything in the error log to indicate what's happening.

I've tried the following methods:

- Going through the Find Participants menu to edit an individual event participant and change their status from Registered to Attended
- Mass updating participants through the Find Participants menu > Select all participants > Participant status - change, then updating several participants' status from Registered to Attended

For either of these methods, I do this and the Civi dialog box says: *Event registration information for [PARTICIPANT NAME] has been updated.*

However on both the Find Participants menu and the participant's contact info page, they're still set to Registered for the event rather than Attended.

I need to update these people to Attended so I can send an email out to those who attended.

Any idea on what can be done to fix this? As mentioned there's nothing in the error log.

Comment: Just checking did you also check drupal watchdog at /admin/reports/dblog?

Comment: Does a one by one update works? This sounds like a bug in civicrm.

Comment: i just did a quick check on a civicrm5.13.5 but on a Wordpress, the change in Participation Status works fine.

Comment: Yep I've checked Drupal error log. I've used the change in participation status previously and it had no issues, no clue why it's acting up now.

Comment: Do you have any custom extension/module/rules which silently ignore status change on participant record ?